# Notebooks are not executed in Spark on Docker

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin 0.10.0 to run Spark jobs, I have installed it on Docker, and once I open Zeppelin to run Notebooks, I got the following error.

org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Fail to detect scala version, the reason is:Cannot run program "null/bin/spark-submit": error=2, No such file or directory
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:129)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:271)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:438)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:69)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue on 0.10.1.  My current workaround is to downgrade to 0.9.0, which doesn't seem to have the same problem as 0.10.1

Answer (score 1):

You could try starting the Zeppelin container with the environment variable `SPARK_HOME` specified, as described in [Play Spark in Zeppelin docker](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#play-spark-in-zeppelin-docker).